# how to make an autosuggest like freebase

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, freebase

i need to make an sutosuggest similar to freebase ...i need to know how can i treansfer the datas from my db

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#myinput").suggest({type:'/film/director'});
});
</script>
```

i have an db i need to get the details from the db how can i do that???

Answer (score 2):

If you have an http service (JSON/P) to your dataset and have a translation layer for the suggest parameters, you should be able to adjust the "service_url" and "service_path" parameters to point to your service:

```
$("#myinput").suggest({
  service_url: "http://yourdomain.com",
  service_path: "/your/json/service"
});
```

Try out a suggest demo ([here](http://www.freebase.com/docs/suggest)) and with Web Inspector/Firebug look at the http requests/responses suggest makes to freebase.com. Your web service must return the same JSON format suggest is expecting. Otherwise, you may need to overwrite the default suggest response handler (which is do-able).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the autocomplete component from jQUery ui.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/